# Java Multithreading: Spread complex workload

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have to create a statistics-application where performance is crutial. In simple words:

- My application recieves a range of numbers (eg. 50.000 - 150.000) - the range can constantly change
- For each number within the range the application should perform network requests and various checks
- Some numbers need to be checked twice or even more often, some just one and some not at all

Sadly, I'm quite new to programming and still learning - so this is what I'm doing so far (please note, some parts are pseudo-code for simplicity):

---

1: Split the range into 100 parts so every Thread has his own range to check (100 Threads used)

```
ArrayList<String> FetchingRanges = new ArrayList<>();
int totalRangeToFetch = rangeStart - rangeEnd; //amount of numbers to check (100.000 in this example)
int rangePerThread = totalRangeToFetch / 100; //Range per thread (10.000 numbers per thread in this example)
int rangeCounter = rangeStart; //this defines the starting point for the loop

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int FROM = rangeCounter;
    rangeCounter+= rangePerThread;
    int TO = rangeCounter;
    rangeCounter++;

    FetchingRanges.add(FROM + ";" + TO);
}
```

2: This gives me an ArrayList "FetchingRanges" filled with partial ranges, eg.

```
FetchingRanges.get(0) -> 50000;60000 //This is what the first thread has to check
FetchingRanges.get(1) -> 60001;70000
//...
FetchingRanges.get(99) -> 140001;150000 //This is what the last thread has to check
```

3: Next, I'm starting 100 Threads and each thread checks its numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int Start = Integer.parseInt(FetchingRanges.get(i).split(";")[0]);
            int End = Integer.parseInt(FetchingRanges.get(i).split(";")[0]);

            for (i = Start; i <= End; i++){
                //... Check Number, Do Network Request, Analyze and Report
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

---

The problem with this solution is simple: I want all the threads to have equal load, but since some numbers are more difficult to check than others, some Threads are just idling and waiting for their next range (which might come in minutes) while on the other hand some Threads are still working and can't finish their work until the next range needs to be checked.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Use a concurrent queue and let each thread pick up a batch of numbers from the queue when they're done with the previous ones

Comment: Why not directly use a thread pool, such as creating a thread pool containing 100 threads? Then all check tasks are submit to this thread pool, no need to be divided into 100 parts.

Comment: in addition to @ErwinBolwidt  Using 100 threads might not be doing what you expect - you probably have no machine which handles this number efficiently. So you shoud consider a thread pool of a useful size.

Comment: I think you can use Executors.newFixedThreadPool fabric method to generate ExecutorService. It takes a number of threads and allocates them upon creation. As long as number of tasks do not exceed number of threads they work concurrently. If at any point number of tasks exceeds number of threads in the pool, they will wait when any thread in pool is finished.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinBolwidt and @zysaaa! I will try both of your suggestions!

Comment: @juwil Thank you for your hint! Actually most of the tasks consist of network requests, I tried quite a lot and on the specific machine I have to use with this specific internet connection, 100 threads seems to be about optimal

Comment: It is best to try to use the thread pool first. The inside of the thread pool is a concurrent queue for storing tasks + a group of threads take tasks from the queue and execute them, and then get new tasks from the queue after execution. You don't need to implement these yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your help in the comments I found the best solution to be ThreadPools. There is no need to split the range into smaller parts for the Threads and alltogether the performance seems to be amazing. This is what I did:

```
public static ExecutorService MyExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

for (int j = Start; j <= End; j++) {
    MyExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){...});
}
```